# How do I reference properties in Json Schema?

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I want to reference each property of the json object in a different file

This is what I'd like to do (but the validations are not working for me):

```
  {
      "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
      "type": "object",
       "properties": 
       {
        "id":      { "$ref": "type/common.json#def_id"    },
        "title":   { "$ref": "type/book.json#def_title" }
      }
    }
```

...

```
# type/common.json   
{
  "def_id":{
    "id": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "uuid",
      "pattern": "^[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}$" 
    }
  }
}

# type/book.json
{
  "def_title":{
    "title": {
      "anyOf": [
        {
          "type": "null"
        },
        
        {
          "type": "string"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

If you could help me I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

I was referencing it wrong, it's work

```
{
  "id":      { "$ref": "type/common.json#/def_id/id"    },
  "title":   { "$ref": "type/book.json#/def_title/title" }
}
```

this works for me